# Why is the same ruby/unicorn version on a new kernel seg faulting?

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, unicorn

I re-built ruby 2.1.1p76 along with all my gems on on a freshly patched Ubuntu LTS 14.04.1 and now my unicorn app gets a Segmentation fault:

```
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/oob_gc.rb:65: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0010 p:---- s:0052 e:000051 CFUNC  :start
c:0009 p:0106 s:0049 e:000048 METHOD /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/oob_gc.rb:65
c:0008 p:0152 s:0044 E:0009c0 METHOD /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632
c:0007 p:0103 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500
c:0006 p:0048 s:0025 e:000024 METHOD /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511
c:0005 p:0244 s:0021 e:000020 METHOD /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277
c:0004 p:0207 s:0014 E:000068 TOP    /var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0092 s:0004 E:001dd8 EVAL   bin/unicorn:16 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:002338 TOP    [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
bin/unicorn:16:in `<main>'
bin/unicorn:16:in `load'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/oob_gc.rb:65:in `process_client'
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/oob_gc.rb:65:in `start'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:38.316228 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 18802 SIGSEGV (signal 11) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:38.507323 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20458 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:38.692126 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20467 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:38.898629 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20477 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:39.139881 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20487 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:39.390072 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20498 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:39.628283 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20507 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:39.833609 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20515 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:40.037082 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20527 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:40.215843 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20536 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:40.407638 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20545 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:40.657763 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20553 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
E, [2015-02-16T21:28:40.854427 #2611] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 20565 SIGILL (signal 4) (core dumped)> worker=1
/var/www/myapp/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/oob_gc.rb:65: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
```

The app never had this happen before.  What could be causing this?  How do I narrow it down?

Along with a bunch of packages updating, the kernel went from linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic to linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic.

Comment: How did you rebuild your gems?

Comment: To be honest, I might have re-used the bundle from the old system.  I'm going to 'bundle install' again to be sure...